# Which Lie groups are also symmetric spaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

I've scanned some of the literature on this, but couldn't find an answer to the following simple questions (probably because I'm not an expert):

Q1: Let G be a Lie group with a left-invariant metric. What are some simple criteria for G to be symmetric, namely, for G to admit, for any point and geodesic through that point, an isometry reversing that geodesic?

Q2: In three dimensions, in terms of the structure constants, one can easily work out essentially all simply-connected groups very concretely. Is there a criterion for going through the list of 3D Lie groups, looking at the structure constants, and deciding which ones are symmetric spaces?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: For Q2, I've implicitly chosen a basis of the Lie algebra, declared it orthonormal, and then took the left-invariant metric corresponding to that. It is in terms of the structure constants arising that way that I ask the question.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose the metric is bi-invariant. (You can always find such a metric if $G$ is compact; see Amitesh Datta's comment below.) Then geodesics starting at the identity are one-parameter subgroups (and by invariance this determines what geodesics are everywhere else), and the isometry reversing those geodesics is $g \mapsto g^{-1}$.

Comment: Hi @Qiaochu, I'm sure you know this already, but you can always find a bi-invariant metric on a compact Lie group: simply pick an inner product at the identity which is Ad-invariant ("Ad" denoting the adjoint representation of the Lie group), and extend it in the obvious left-invariant manner to a Riemannian metric on all of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

An answer to Q2 is:
$G$ is a symmetric space if and only if the left-invariant metric is bi-invariant.

The answer of Qiaochu Yuan explains why this is a sufficient criterion.
It remains to check that it is also a necessary criterion.
To this end, assume $G$ is endowed with a left-invariant, but not a bi-invariant metric, and is a symmetric space.
Then, $G$ must be one of the symmetric spaces from Cartan's classification https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space#Classification_result .
None of those symmetric spaces have dimension 3, which is a contradiction.

An answer to Q1 that is useless for general proofs, but may be helpful in special cases, is:
For $G$ to be a symmetric space, it has to be in one of two classes:

1. $G$ is endowed with a bi-invariant metric.
2. $G$ is endowed with a left-invariant, but not bi-invariant metric.

In case 1 it is automatically a symmetric space, as stated above.

In case 2 it is isometric to a symmetric space $M=B/K$.
The Iwasawa decomposition $\mathfrak{b}=\mathfrak{k \oplus a \oplus n}$ gives rise to a subgroup $AN \subset B$.
This subgroup carries a left-invariant metric and is isometric to $M$, and therefor to $G$.
So, a necessary and sufficient criterion for $G$ to be a symmetric space is that it is isometric to the Iwasa subgroup $AN$ of some symmetric space.
Of course, this in itself is not helpful at all.
However, one could write down a list of all possible $AN$, and then check if a given $G$ appears in the list.
If it does, it is a Riemannian space.
If it does not, one has to check whether it is isometric to any entry in the list, which is admittedly difficult.